# Converting string into json in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have been saving one hash into database field, which have type text, so when i take it from table, it looks like

```
"---\nnew: test1\ndelivered:\n  mess: delete\n"

def check_type
 final_text =  "---\nnew: test1\ndelivered:\n  mess: delete\n"
 final_json = YAML.load(final_text)
 first_val = final_json["new"]
end
```

for getting this string as hash, i have used the YAML to convert that string into hash, its working fine, my question is there any other way instead of using this YAML to convert this string to hash

Comment: `JSON.parse` you can use..

Comment: Then your JSON string is malformed. Fixed it

Comment: Do you think `"---\nnew: test1\ndelivered:\n  mess: delete\n"` is a JSON string. This is a `YAML` string, and how you would convert an YAML to JSON directly.. `YAML.load` is giving you a `Hash`, not a `JSON`... Do test it by your self like `YAML.load(string).class`..

Comment: sorry that was my mistake when typing that, i have changed that in my question, yes you're correct, it gives the hash

Comment: When you have an _yaml_ string, then to get a `Hash` from the string, you need to use `YAML::load` method. Why you are not liking `YAML::load` method, btw ? :D

Comment: ya, that the exact way i had used, is there any issues i mean any security issues?

Comment: :D, actually i did this code one month before, then after some searching i got about this YAML.load("string"), anyway you found that mistake in my question, liked :D

Comment: security issues would be a secondary concern with post processing not with data type conversion.